# CircuiTikZ —How to create Constant Phase Element (CPE) used in Electrochemistry

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

Good day, Can anyone help with how to create a new component in circuittikz. I am trying to create the CPE element shown in the figure below instead of the standard capacitor element. i have searched but could not find an easy guide on how to create a cicruit element.[image]

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: I could not find any alternatives. I have just downloaded some documents on how to make my own custom elements. It would take me a little while to do though

Comment: Could you provide a picture for those of us who don't know what a constant phase element is? How about the top component in [this image](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Randles-equivalent-circuit-with-a-constant-phase-element-R-S-solution-resistance_fig7_225596326)?

Comment: Thanks Willoughby. I have added the image. You are right.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us the code and describe what problem you have with it.

Comment: @Werner -- The question that you cite is by the same person, has no answer, and is closed for lack of detail (by you among others), although it has been nominated for reopening.  What's really needed here is an understandable explanation of exactly what should be added to make the question answerable.  Actually, it would be better to reopen the other question (I will add my vote) and remove this one, which is now best done by the OP.

Comment: @barbara beeton -- It still makes this question a duplicate. OP already got comments what people want him to provide (code,more details) but instead he asked the question again. So far it looks like a do it for me question.

Comment: @Roland -- I didn't say it wasn't a "do it for me" question.  I was just trying to point out that a new visitor to the site won't be familiar with how the community works.  No one has pointed this person to the question that says how to provide an MWE or to something that says why a "do it for me" question isn't appreciated.  That would be the polite thing to do.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I agree. My posting is the default addition by SE when casting a close vote; I knew it was a duplicate of the original posting. True, the other one should be reopened once the OP has added the necessary details.

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- I think I (and José Carlos Santos ) asked him kindly for the code and the problem he has with it. Which is basically asking for a MWE. Yes I missed to point out what a MWE. I never saw the need of telling him that "do it for me" questions are not appreciated, because until "this question" it did not look like one. Would he had responded to the comments the question would not be closed. So, it looked like he abandoned the question by asking the same again.

Comment: @Roland -- Actually, he did react to a comment asking him to confirm that what he wanted matched a linked image.  He added the image (after the question was closed, which was only 3 hours after posting).  I suspect he may not have fully understood that what was really wanted was compilable code showing what he'd done so far, but did say earlier that doing that would take "some time".

Comment: @barbara beeton -- If you would be so kind to point out where he saked for conformation? Quote: "Thanks Willoughby. I have added the image. You are right." is not asking for conformation. Also he never responded to my comment which was the last one. Even if a question is closed you still can edit it and leave a comment. He mentions it would take him time to make his own custom elemts. Fine, take the time, the question does not disappear. Instead he copy pasted the question which led me to the conclusion that he never intended to work on it.

Comment: @barbara beeton -- Finally, this could all be a big misunderstanding, but instead of creating clarity and maybe asking OP yourself, you criticize others who voted to close the question. Although the reasons are quite understandable.

Comment: My bad. I should have posted a MWE of what I tried to do. This is my first time. Now I know how to do it right. meanwhile the question has been answered by John. Thank you.

Comment: @Roland -- I do think this is all a big misunderstanding.  What I was criticizing was not that the other question was closed, but the fact that the pointer was given without any additional explanation.  I've no idea who in this group is a native English speaker, but the very fine distinction I was implying is often missed by someone who has not grown up in a native English-speaking community.  *I* should have been more clear.

Comment: Ok, I didn't resist: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/576 --- please chime in if you want (@john-kormyolo too!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `\pgfcircdeclarebipole` does all the heavy lifting.  The only tricky part is drawing with PGF primatives.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
% *************************** CPE **********************************

\ctikzset{bipoles/CPE/height/.initial=.6}
\ctikzset{bipoles/CPE/width/.initial=.4}

\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}
 {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/CPE/height}}
 {CPE}
 {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/CPE/height}}
 {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/CPE/width}}
 {
    \pgf@circ@res@step = \ctikzvalof{bipoles/CPE/width}\pgf@circ@Rlen
        \divide \pgf@circ@res@step by 5

        \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\dimexpr \pgf@circ@res@left+2\pgf@circ@res@step}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}

        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\dimexpr \pgf@circ@res@right-2\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\dimexpr \pgf@circ@res@right-2\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
    
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfstartlinewidth}% connect to circuit
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\dimexpr \pgf@circ@res@left+2\pgf@circ@res@step}{0pt}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}
}

\pgfcirc@activate@bipole@simple{l={#1}}{CPE}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[CPE] (2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Nice, +1, but better use `\pgfcirc@activate@bipole@simple{l}{CPE}` instead of the two last lines (see page 200 in https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0). In your case, you should use `l={#1}` (notice the braces) otherwise a label like `CPE={$a=b$}` will fail.

Comment: @Rmano - Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a new component, there is a tutorial [in the final part of the `circuitikz` manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0#section.9). Admittedly, that is not easy-peasy --- in this case, I would start with a simple component, like a capacitor or a generic rectangular bipole, and tweak it.

But as a simpler approach, you can just use normal Ti*k*Z commands to draw it. In my code below I draw a CPE that is horizontal and span from `(in)` to `(in)++(2,0)`. It is not as flexible as a *true* component, but you can easily put the `\draw` (heavily commented) into a macro.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) to[R=$R_s$] ++(2,0) coordinate(n1) -- ++(0,1) coordinate(in);
    % this is the CPE with its wire (it occupies a ++(2,0) horizontal span
    % horizonatl wire; I put it slightly yo the right cause it looks better
    \draw (in) -- ++(1,0) coordinate(cpe1) ++(0.2,0) coordinate(cpe2) 
    -- ++(0.8,0) coordinate(out)
    % "arms"
    (cpe1) -- ++(-0.2,0.4) (cpe1) -- ++(-0.2,-0.4)
    (cpe2) -- ++(-0.2,0.4) (cpe2) -- ++(-0.2,-0.4)
    % label
    (cpe1)  ++(0,0.4) node[above]{CPE};
   % rest of the circuit
\draw (n1) -- ++(0,-1) to[R, l_=$R_{\mathit{ct}}$] ++(2,0)
    -- ++(0,1) coordinate(n2) -- (out) (n2) --++(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also prepare a component request for the package; notice however that I will consider things if the request has relevant links to the "standard" component definition, possibly with relative dimensions and so on. To see a nicely done component request, look at https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/383 for example.

Comment: The element will be available starting from version 1.4.2, see https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/577